# Is it correct to put WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED) inside update block in select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
 UPDATE
        BondPrices
    SET
        MarketValueOwned = Holdings.Amount
    FROM
        BondPrices BondPrices
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                PM.SecurityId,
                SUM(Pos.QuantityTraded * Pos.Mark) AS Amount
            FROM
                Position Pos --WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED)
                INNER JOIN
                PositionMaster PM --WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED)
                       ON
                    Pos.PositionMasterId = PM.PositionMasterId
            WHERE
                Pos.Date = @ReportDate 
            GROUP BY
                PM.SecurityId
        ) Holdings ON
            BondPrices.SecurityId = Holdings.SecurityId
    WHERE
        BondPrices.Date = @ReportDate
```

please help me is that correct that i put WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED) inside select statement of update block?
i need to do this for reporting purpose but i'm confused whether it is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Table Hints (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

> READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK cannot be specified for tables modified by insert, update, or delete operations. The SQL Server query optimizer ignores the READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints in the FROM clause that apply to the target table of an UPDATE or DELETE statement.

Tables `Fireball..Position` and `Fireball_Reporting..PositionMaster` aren't modified so this hint should be fine.

**Edit:**

I assume that you wanted write `READUNCOMMITTED` instead of `UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: We do not know what else is modifying Position and Position master when the report is running

Comment: @Andrew, you are right about the whole report. My answer is based only on shown query.

Comment: yea right i'm taking about WITH (NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED)
i just want to know whether it is correct to use it how i did or not? because it is in update block but for select statement?

Comment: I think it's correct **until you accept dirty reads** from those tables, because: *No shared locks are issued to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not block the current transaction from reading the locked data.*

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to judge whether the NOLOCK hint is correct or not without understanding why it was placed in there.

The intention is that it will place no row / pages locks and should not get blocked from reading, but it doesnt prevent locking entirely since a Sch-S lock (Schema Stability Lock) will still be issued.

The no lock comes at a price however, you could read uncommited / dirty data and not be transactionally consistent, a NOLOCK can even theoretically read the same row twice.

The UNCOMMITTED hint doesnt make sense in that is not a valid hint - it is perhaps supposed to be READUNCOMMITED, which is another way of specifying NOLOCK - so that part seems pointless.

Comment: `READCOMMITED` can also read the same row twice but it is less likely. You need `REPEATABLEREAD` to completely avoid this possibility and that can still miss rows if the index key is changed with an `update` during the scan.

Comment: @Martin - via page split on an update whilst a scan is running?

Comment: No. Page Splits will affect the allocation ordered scan that `nolock` might use. If the key is updated during the index ordered scan then the row can be moved to later in the index and be read twice.

Comment: Makes sense - I remember Lubor Koller did an articale about NOLOCK and double reads some time back where he detailed out the scenarios